# How can I refresh a Jquery/javascript variable on click without reloading page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'll preface this by saying that this seems like something that must have been asked before but, surprisingly, my Googling only turned up tangentially related results.

I have the following code, which is meant to have the following features:

1) Randomly assigns one of 3 values to a variable (`VariableVar1random`) every time the page loads

2) A button that shows a square on click

3) A button that re-assigns one of the 3 values to the variable without refreshing the page.  For example, let's say on page load, the variable generates as "Variable3". If I click on the button that shows the square and then click on the button that re-assigns the value of the variable, the variable should regenerate as either "Variable1" or "Variable2" WITHOUT refreshing the page (square is still showing).

I've tried removeData() among other functions but cannot seem to find anything that works. Is AJAX necessary?

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/asb7bx6p/20/

HTML

```
<span class="VariableVar1randomreplacer"></span>

<br>
<br>
<div class="buttonresetvariable" style="border:1px solid black;">Click to Reset Variable</div>
<br>
<div class="buttonshowsquare" style="border:1px solid black;">Click to Show Square</div>

<div class="alertsquare" style="display:none;border:1px solid black;height:50px;width:50px;background-color:green;"></div>
```

JQUERY

```
 function Variableselector1() {

    var VariableVar1= ['Variable1', 'Variable2', 'Variable3'];
    var VariableVar1random = VariableVar1[Math.floor(Math.random() * VariableVar1.length)];
    return VariableVar1random;
}

    var VariableVar1randomreplacer = Variableselector1();
    $('.VariableVar1randomreplacer').html(VariableVar1randomreplacer );

$( ".buttonshowsquare" ).click(function() {
$( ".alertsquare").show();
});

$( ".buttonresetvariable" ).click(function() {
////???????????????
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for the first glance this will fit in:

```
$( ".buttonresetvariable" ).click(function() {
   var VariableVar1randomreplacer = Variableselector1();
   $('.VariableVar1randomreplacer').html(VariableVar1randomreplacer );
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/asb7bx6p/22/

> Is AJAX necessary?

In your case you already got all the data to manipulate with on your client.
Briefly `AJAX` request is necessary when you need to interact/get some data from remote server.

Comment: I KNEW it had to be ridiculously simple...thank you so much!

Comment: @Snoops You can shorten the line btw too: `$('.VariableVar1randomreplacer').html(Variableselector1());` not necesarry to create a var for it.

Comment: @Doomenik yep, you right, but to keep things closer to OP's post

Comment: @DanilGholtsman Yes of course just wanted to give him a small hint.

Comment: Thank you, all...small nudges in the right direction like this really help.